# The meaning of "This state seems to have been quite as much Vallachian as Bulgarian."

Tags: meaning, expressions

> This state seems to have been quite as much Vallachian as Bulgarian.

I assume that the meaning of the sentence is that the state is half Vallachian and half Bulgarian. I am not sure though, can somebody point it out to me?

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: History SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be its literal meaning, but it was probably not intended to be interpreted literally. Far more likely, it was intended to convey the message that calling it either Bulgarian or Vallachian would be a mistake because it partook strongly of both.

Comment: As @Matt Gutting says: 'Hi! What we're really looking for (on this or any other Stack Exchange site) is a supported answer; one that you can support with authoritative references (in this case an encyclopedia ... or some other such document). Edit your question and put in your support; then we'll be able to vote up your answer!' Though I'd say this is 75+% history rather than English.